# Swift, cannot invoke objc_setAssociatedObject with an argument list of type

Tags: xcode, swift

Xcode 6.4   swift 1.2

How can I do?
Thanks everyone

See this error

[image]

Comment: provide the code, nobody would want to retype from the screenshot to troubleshoot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &loadOperationKey, operations, UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
```